# Find UI elements in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing an issue regarding UI elements in unity.

I am making a leader board as in Piano tiles for all Facebook friends score.

I tried instantiating UI elements at run time but cant implement. I want to assign random values to UI Text and UI images in for loop.

I made and array of panels and and activate and deactivate them according to my requirement.

I get the parent but I don't know how to find its children (these child are UI elements) and assign a value.

Comment: dude just go "public Text headline1" "public Text headline2" and so on - have many of them if needs be - and drag to connect them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the 'parent' GameObject you can do:

```
parent.transform.Find("Name").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Whatever";
```

Comment: yes I tried this but i have multiple names like a friend list how can i make "Name" dynamic as i want to change in for each value of i in my for loop

Comment: If you have a defined spot where all those elements are (like the parent object in hierarchy), you could just iterate over those, since they are basically a list. This way you don't actually need the name to find it because you have a reference to the element with the component.

Comment: Thanks to both of u guys ...i make all the UI elements of same name but their parent name is different so in a loop it assigns value against certain parent name .... Thank you so much

Comment: One thing i wana ask @Vancete Using the same line of code can we find UI image having the same parent as i found text using above line of code like                                                                                         Image.sprite=  Parent.transform.Find("Photo").GetComponent<Image>().sprite ;

Comment: Yup, it should work in the same way. Take care that 'parent' is the name of the variable containing your parent GameObject.